# Can Picasso crop an image without scaling?

Tags: android, picasso

I have an image that I'm trying to load with Picasso that I want to crop *without* scaling.
Is this possible?

For example, if I had:

- an image that's 400x800
- an image view that's 200x400

Any questions I've seen regarding cropping suggest using `resize(x, y).centreCrop(alignGravity)` (i.e. scaling and cropping rather than only cropping).

In the example, you'd get the entire image scaled to 50%, as the JavaDocs for `centreCrop` mentions:

> This cropping technique scales the image so that it fills the requested bounds and then crops the extra, preferring the contents at `alignGravity`.

I want to display the middle 200x400 pixels of the image and lose the edges entirely (similar to how [ImageMagick's crop would work](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop)).

Is there a way to crop without scaling?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that out-of-the-box, no it doesn't, but you can use the [Picasso Transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) library to do so:

```
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.4.0'
```

and then:

```java
Picasso.get()
       .load(largeImage)
       .transform(new CropTransformation(width, height, GravityVertical.CENTER, GravityVertical.CENTER))
       .into(imageView, /* callback */);
```

If you are using `resize()` or `centreCrop()` you need to use after the call to `transform()`.